# Access of host TPM for VirtualBox Guest Win10?

Tags: dual-boot, virtualbox, tpm

I've recently installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 on my corporate laptop in a dualboot setting. There are things I need the enterprise Win10 installation for. I've successfully used VirtualBox in the past to boot into the "physical" (raw) hard drive, but this time due to my company's policies TPM has to exist and be enabled before I access any corporate resources.

I did check, and my Ubuntu host can see and access the TPM 2.0 chip my laptop has.

I'm asking if it is possible to give the guest OS running in VirtualBox access to the physical TPM chip? I think a virtualized TPM 2.0 chip might not cut it as the existing Win10 installation would still freak out? (I'm not sure as I'm no expert on how TPM works in an enterprise setting)
Also, I wanna keep the ability to dual-boot and also to spin up my Windows partition as a VM. Is this possible at all?

Thanks!

EDIT:
I upgraded to VirtualBox 7, which apparently has TPM support. Out of the box it only lets me select a virtualized TPM, but based on the documentation I have ran the following command:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm win10raw --tpm-type=host --tpm-location=/dev/tpm0
```

When I went to start the VM, it complained of access denied error for the TPM.
Then I enabled some [udev rules](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tss/blob/master/dist/tpm-udev.rules) to allow my user to access TPM, after that I was able to boot the VM up, though Windows still claims there was a TPM failure. Upon further investigation, the Guest Windows still thinks there's no TPM, so there might be a reason why "Host" is not an option on the VirtualBox GUI.